# Can I put files on the iPad simulator?

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

I need to create an app that plays a video on the iPad.  Is there a way that I can put an FLV (or any other files for that matter)on the iPad simulator so that I can test the app that will open the video file?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. Look under `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator` for the file system of the simulator. Look under Applications. One of the UUIDs will be your app, and you'll find its Documents folder, etc in there.

(The poor man's way of doing this for testing is of course by just sticking it in your Xcode project and loading it from the bundle.)